# v$sqlarea is not accessible in oracle apex 3.2.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I logged into Oracle Apex through my company server. I am not able to get `sql_text` from `v$sqlarea` view. I am stuck, and don't be able to proceed further to kill sessions.

Comment: Improve code format, and typo correction.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you don't have access to view those tables, to give access ask you dba to grant this ,

```
SQL> grant all on v_$sqlarea to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Instead of scott, replace with your username

Comment: Thank u for reply...could u tell me this one also..                                    After getting report by sql commands in apex,I want to store data of variables sid,serial# corresponding to check boxes which are checked.After that i have to execute alter system kill session 'sid,serial#' in apex itself

Comment: Which one? What are you referring to

Comment: After getting report by sql commands in apex,I want to store data of variables sid,serial# corresponding to check boxes which are checked.After that i have to execute alter system kill session 'sid,serial#' in apex itself

Comment: @Hemanth , am not well versed with apex, you can upvote answer if it has helped solve your earlier issue. :)